# Why does white LCD screen look coloured when there is a drop of water?

Tags: optics

When we put some water on an LCD screen showing completely white color, it shows RGB colors.

Why does this happen?

Is this due to some kind of magnification of the pixels due to the curved surface of water acting as a lens?

Comment: To see pixels without help of water try to look at the turned-on TV screen from $1$ cm distance. Water just magnifies the pixels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, at least for my LCD screen.
I could see the pixels on my PSP with water droplets.
The white you're seeing from your screen is made up of red, blue and green lights from the individual pixels in the LCD screen. Far enough they look white, but when zoomed in they are separated colours.